# Could jQuery .post() stop trying to enforce the "guessed" dataType?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, smarty

I have the following setup:

The main web project consists of a large(ish) PHP script with a HTML table as its central part. The last table row is intended to be able to add copies of itself. For this purpose I put it into a separate `Smarty` template file:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>key row 1</td>
    <td>still row 1</td>
    <td>another row 1 <div>with some Div here</div></td>
  </tr>
  {include "new-row.tpl"}
</table>
```

`new-row.tpl` (more or less):

```
{strip}
<tr>
  <td onBlur="newRow()">key row x</td>
  <td>still row x</td>
  <td>another row x <div>with some Div here</div></td>
</tr>
{/strip}
```

`newRow()`:

```
function newRow() {
  $.post(
    "/add-new-row.php", // only displays the new-row.tpl
    {
      param: "doit"
    },
    function(data) {
      alert(data);
      $("table tr:last").after(data);
    }
  );
}
```

Inspecting what's happening with Firebug's network monitor shows me that `data` actually gets the right response (the complete `<tr>`), but suddenly the whole table structure disappears from `data` when trying to `alert` it, leaving only the content alive.

I found out that jQuery seems to *parse* the AJAX-retrieved HTML code. As it doesn't contain a `<table>` tag, jQuery discards all table structure elements before passing them. I have to explicitly state that my `dataType` is `text`; when I do so, everything is fine.

Is this expected behavior or can I, somehow, tell jQuery to take my valid HTML excerpt as a valid HTML excerpt even if it's only a bare table row?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your server say `Content-Type: text/html`? You shouldn't say that if you aren't returning an HTML document.

Comment: *"I found out that jQuery seems to parse the AJAX-retrieved HTML code."* I can't make it do that, and [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) says it returns HTML as text. When I try with `$.post` calling a PHP file that returns `Content-Type: text/html`, I get back text in the callback. Are you perhaps serving your HTML as XML?

Comment: According to Firebug, it's `text/html`. Is there a decent doctype for HTML parts?

Comment: I'm flummoxed. All due respect, I know that jQuery does not parse `text/html` responses. I think there must be a different problem, e.g., that there was an observational error somewhere.

Comment: Well, given that just adding `text` as a `.post` parameter makes me retrieve the correct HTML part, I wonder what else I may have missed. :/

Comment: jQuery shouldn't discard elements like that. If you have invalid elements though, not everything will be inserted by jQuery. For example: <tr></td>Test</td</tr> (note the first td tag, in which case the after() method will only insert <tr></tr>). Maybe that might be the problem?

Comment: As the `<tr><td>...` is even missing when I `alert` the response right after receiving it, I already concluded that this can't be the reason. :/